# Symfony 3 save form data from entity without association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

In my blog form I have field with authors:

```
<?php
$this->add(
    'user',
    EntityType::class,
    [
        'label'       => 'Author',
        'class'       => 'Hitso\Bundle\CommonBundle\Entity\User',
        'placeholder' => 'Select post author',
        'mapped'      => false,
        'empty_data'  => null,
    ]
)
```

But in my Blog entity I haven't user association with users table, I have this in other table - 'blogs_users':

```
<?php
/**
 * Blog
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blogs")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class Blog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10, options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     */
    private $slug;

  }
```

And my BlogUser entity class:

```
<?php
/**
 * BlogUsers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blogs_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BlogBundle\Repository\BlogUserRepository")
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class BlogUser implements SiteIdAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BlogBundle\Entity\Blog")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @var \Hitso\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog
     */
    private $blog;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BlogBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     * @var CommonBundle\Entity\User
     */
    private $user; 
}
```

And my BlogController::newAction :

```
<?php
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $blog = new Blog();

    $form = $this->createForm(
        BlogType::class,
        $blog
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $blogUser = new BlogUser();
        $em->persist($blogUser);

        $em->persist($blog);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('...');
    }
```

But right now wen I submit the form I have error below:

**Property user does not exist in class BlogBundle\Entity\Blog**

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do correct annotation targetEntity on user attribute of blog user

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CommonBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
 * @var CommonBundle\Entity\User
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: No this not help. This was just my mistake in question.